# Migrate data between two databases with different layouts

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing a new site, I have to migrate it's old data to the new database, which has a new layout structure.
 I'm finding hard to migrate, the multiple addresses that one person might have.
Just a detail, when I'm inserting these clients from the old db, I'm letting auto incremental sets it's ID, so new clients ID will be different from the old database table, should I keep them the same?
Consider the follow tables structures:
**CLIENT TABLE**:

```
#|id_client|#|name|#
#|    1    |#|John|#
#|    2    |#|Bob |#
#|    3    |#|Karl|#
```

This table is easy to migrate, I only have to do:

```
INSERT INTO NEW_DB.CLIENT SELECT * FROM (SELECT id_cliente,name FROM OLD_DB.CLIENT)
```

But what if I have an addresses table, that an user might have 0..n addresses?
 How will I insert it with the FK reference to Client.id_client, remembering that the new client ID is different from the old one?

```
#|id_address|#|address|#|Client_id_client
#|    1     |#|Addr123|#|       1
#|    2     |#|Addr321|#|       1
#|    3     |#|Addr124|#|       2
```

Comment: Well, keeping the old ID made it quite simple, but it would be good if anyone could tell me how it would be done without using the old IDS, but letting auto incremental set them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a completely portable script and not depend on auto generated ids, you need to determine the unique columns in your CLIENT table that identify the client (other than the id).

Assuming name is the unique attribute on you client table, you could insert data into your address table like so:

```
INSERT INTO NEW_DB.ADDRESS (COL1, COL2,..., CLIENT_ID)
SELECT OLD_DB.ADDRESS.COL1,  OLD_DB.ADDRESS.COL2,... 
(SELECT NEW_DB.CLIENT.CLIENT_ID from NEW_DB.CLIENT WHERE NEW_DB.CLIENT.NAME = OLD_DB.CLIENT.NAME) 
FROM OLD_DB.ADDRESS, OLD_DB.CLIENT 
WHERE OLD_DB.ADDRESS.CLIENT_ID =  OLD_DB.CLIENT.CLIENT_ID
```